# Identify the a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need to identify each of these 'a' tag in div and bind an onclick event.I have binded the same.I need to append some text below the clicked 'a' tag.But when i tried with my code it binds to all the 'a' tag in the div.How can i specify the 'a' tag which i have clicked.I can make changes to the content in div using jquery.can't modify the content in 'a' tag.

```
    <div class="people_rt_link2">
    <a href="#" title="2011">2011</a><br><br>
    <a href="#" title="2008">2008</a><br><br>
    </div>

    $(document).ready(function() {
      var timesClicked = 0;
      $('.people_rt_link2 a').bind('click', function() {

        jQuery.post("<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/test.php", data, function(response) {
               alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
               //this response should to binded to the clicked a tag
                //$(this).after('<div>'+response+'</div>');
         });
        timesClicked++;
       if (timesClicked >= 1) {
          $(this).unbind();
       }

     });
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `this` to refer to the clicked `<a>`. Example using jQuery:

```
$('div.people_rt_link2 a').click(function(){
    $(this).unbind('click');
    var that = this;
    $.post('somepage.php', function(data){
        $(that).after(data);
    });
    return false;
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/QTuKp/)

Let me know if that's not exactly what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi paulPRO, I have got this solution and it works fine.But how can i achieve the same inside a jquery post.On the a tag click an ajax is performed and i need to get the response from the server and append it to the clicked anchor tag.

Comment: @Gins, I updated my post to make a POST request to `somepage.php` and insert the data after the ajax request completes.

Comment: @Gin you can't use `this` inside the Ajax callback since `this` has a different meaning there. See how I use `var that = this;` so I can refer to `that` in the callback.

Comment: @Gin Also just so you know, `timesClicked` is global for all `<a>`s the way you have your code setup. If you want to only allow each link to be clicked once then you should just unbind at the beginning of the click handler like in my code above.

Comment: ,Sorry my mistake...it worked like a charm....It was all of a sudden...before i thought of a solution u were here...Thanks again:)

Answer (score 0):

Theres lots of ways to specify the a tag you want to append text too.. first child.. first of type.. but mostly you just append an id to the tag and let javascript handle it..

```
$("people_rt_link2 a.YourClass").bind("click", function({do stuff}));
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
$("people_rt_link2 a").bind("click", foo(<!--Put here all your code you want to be executed -->));
```